# Get HTML/DOM from a running web browser

Tags: html, linux, windows, dom, browser

I apologize if this question is too generic, if it is please feel free to edit. I am designing an A.I. system which is to monitor/observe human interaction with a desktop environment and learn from it.
I may use image captures and computer vision, but this adds a layer of complexity concerning the interacted elements on the screen.
I was wondering if there is a way to get the actual DOM or HTML elements a user interacts with (mouse click, on focus, kb input, etc) directly from the browser. 
In windows, I may be able to hook a DLL into the browser, but in Linux I have no idea how to do something similar. The idea behind this is that when user clicks on "Button" LOG IN, instead of capturing image pixels using CV, I actually get the data structure of the element the user interacted with. How may I do something like this ? The engine will be a service developed in C/C++.

Comment: What do you mean by getting the data structure of the element?

Comment: @Sibi Any kind of information on what the element the interaction took place, is. Is it a button, is it a link, etc ? Using computer vision this kind of inference is really hard if not impossible.

Comment: Just in case you haven't heard about [heatmap](http://www.squidoo.com/heat-map).

Comment: @Sibi that is interesting, but beyond the scope of my research. Thank you though, I can see how this would be useful in certain scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are monitoring a desktop environment, I have the following suggestion for the Linux environment.

1. Try to capture the XWindow Events. Since window managers like KDE, GNOME etc are built on top of it, that may give you additional information.
2. With respect to browser, as others have stated it would be best to go with plugin. It is also a cross-platform solution.

A starting point for X event watcher is given [here](http://www.rahul.net/kenton/events.html#ASimple). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for making this distinction. Although most interests lie in a the browser interaction, I do not want to exclude other Desktop interactions. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

The [Selenium plugin](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for Firefox, which is usually used for testing, has a record/playback mechanism that may be capable of logging the types of events you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your software could prompt a user to install a browser extension, then you could easily write a different extension for each browser.  These are relatively simple to write.

You could either find some open-source code you could embed in your extension, such as the Selenium codebase, or simply use a JavaScript library (jQuery?) to capture all browser events and send the ones that look like user interaction (click, scroll, etc) to your system along with DOM details and any other data.  Maybe have your engine expose a REST service for integration.

Be careful about performance, though - depending how much you're sending you may need to implement a work queue and batch events up or you could slow down their browser.

OTOH, if you need to leave their browser alone, then I don't believe you will be able to programmatically determine the HTML/DOM structure backing the pixels on-screen.  At least, not with any tool I know of, and logic backs this up:  since every browser implements DOM manipulation and display using their own codebase, the format of the data in memory is anybody's guess.

Comment: That looks like a simple enough solution. This is for research, so no prompts required, just me and a few testers playing with it. Thank you! I am assuming this is for Firefox only, but I could do something similar in Chrome ?

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward for Chrome... just have to write an extension with a .js file that does the magic:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html